# How does preventDefault cancel a default action on element?

Tags: javascript, w3c

I wondered how in a browser work preventing actions on the default elements. So I toward to whatwg spec, I opened [dispatch](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch) algorithm and began read.

In the end [I found the following](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-canceled-flag%E2%91%A4):

> Return false if event’s canceled flag is set; otherwise true.

I know that operation [preventDefault](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-preventdefault) sets [canceled flag](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#canceled-flag), so if an event was invoked and event's callback called [preventDefault](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-preventdefault) it means that [dispatch](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch) operation return false.

But spec doesn't say what it does with value from [dispacth](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch) and where value from it go away.

**So my question is:** "How does browser cancel default behaviour"?

**Extra:** "Does whatwg describe how implementation interact with result from dispatch"?

Comment: "_preventDefault sets [internal] canceled flag_". The default action (what ever it is) checks the flag, and continues only if it's not set.

Comment: @Teemu I know it. Question in another thing. Where spec describes it, if it does.

Comment: Canceling the default action is not a generic process, what should processes do if the flag is set is, where applicable, described on every process description in the standard.

Comment: @Teemu well, could you show me examples with that processes?

Comment: [Form submission algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm) sets _shouldContinue_ flag (at #5.5) based on the [fired event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire), which returns `false` (#5) if the [dispatched event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch) detects _canceled flag_ being set for the event (#5.12), otherwise `true`. The algorithm is cancelled when _shouldContinue_ is `false` (#5.7).

Comment: basically the event happens (eg scroll ) then the listener functions will be called first and then the browser executes the default action which is to scroll the page

Comment: and if `passive=true` the browser will not care about your functions but execute them concurrently

Comment: To clarify my comment above, the parenthed list items are found on the pages linked before them, except the last one, which is on the same page as the first one. The main list item numbers being the same is co-incidental.

Comment: @Teemu very grateful you. Your example excellent describe how algorithm stops when it gets from dispatch value false.